# can't get the PID of running process in terminal

Tags: terminal

The error that I am getting is that when trying to run a project I get the error saying that the port is already occupied. so I run the command `$ lsof -i :<PORT>` the problem is that after running this command it exits with error-1 so I am trying to find a way that I can echo this error to the terminal (iterm2) so I can better trouble shoot this. Because after running the various commands I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac) it doesn't work. I enter the command, I get the error-1, and then run the service again and get the same error saying that the port is already in use

Comment: Try to run it as `root` user

Comment: thanks @RomeoNinov I'm an idiot sometimes! but would you know how to `echo` the error to the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

To run successfully such command is good to do it as `root` user:

```
sudo lsof -i :<PORT>
```

You will need passwordless user for `sudo` or you should enter your password (effect of `sudo`)
To keep the error for future operations you can try command like:

```
ERROR1=$(sudo lsof -i :<PORT> 2>&1 1>&2)
echo $ERROR1
```

This will redirect STDERR to handler of STDOUT and then redirect STDOUT to STDERR handler (switch places) so save in variable the STDERR where usually the errors are printed